# Couchbase 5.0 with Spring-boot XML configuration

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

**How to Spring-boot XML configuration with couchbase 5.0?**

***Full story:*** Recently, **upgraded couchbase server from 4.0.0-4051 to 5.0.0 build 3519** (both are community versions).
Couchbase 4.0 was a bucket based authorization and couchbase 5.0 became Role-Based Access Control (RBAC). (user can have an access to particular buckets).
I have a Spring-boot application which all configs are through XML beans. It works perfectly with couchbase 4.0 but when I change to couchbase 5.0 (note all credentials are CORRECT) I get following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>       ... 25 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' available
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>       ... 38 more

My dependencies are:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I can overcome this issue through manual couchbase client configuration (I already made a sample and tested.) through this code (as explained here https://blog.couchbase.com/new-sdk-authentication/):

`Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create();
cluster.authenticate("username", "password");
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("bucket-name");`

(If source required here it is https://github.com/mashhur/twitter_blockchain)

Anyway XML option would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better RBAC support with Spring Boot and Spring Data is on the way.  It's in the current milestones and should be in a release soon!  See [DATACOUCH-322](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACOUCH-322) targeted to Kay SR6 and Lovelace M2.

Also, note you can make 5.0 behave like earlier releases by simply creating a user whose name is the same as the bucket.

Comment: "make 5.0 behave like earlier releases" - where is this in the documentation ? can you maybe just point me in a direction please.